# Z-index problem with absolute positioned element in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, positioning, z-index

I have a textarea with a connector div that represents a users current status. The connector-div is absolute positioned so that it together with the textarea forms a talk-bubble to symbolize what the user is "saying". The connector is to be placed "on top" of the textarea (normally a higher z-index) and it works fine in every browser but IE7 which I unfortunatly have to support. In IE7 the connector-div is placed below the textarea and thats the issue.

I've googled the issue with Z-index bug in IE7 and tried several solutions i've found but none has solved it for my particular case.

I have the following simplified html:

"

```
  <form class="current-status">
    <div class="talk-bubble">
      <div class="connector"> "Absolute positioned with high z-index.." </div>
      <textarea> "User status goes here" </textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
```

"

current-status-div is just static positioned,
talk-bubble-div is relative,
connector-div is absolute with z-index 4,
textarea is relative and currently has no z-index since it works everywhere but ie7. 
But I tried setting low z-index on texarea and high on connector but IE7 has wierd stacking..

Ive tried lots of different solutions with positioning, z-indexing, wrapping elements etc. but nothing seems to work.

anyone have an idea?

some css connected to the issue:

```
.content-box-plate {
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

.talk-bubble {
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

.connector {
    background: url("/images/portal/bubble_connector.png?1314369295") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 21px;
    z-index: 4;
}
textarea {
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 165px;
    z-index: auto (tried to put a specific value lower than connectors without effect)
}
```

Comment: Where is the CSS? Seems odd to ask a question about CSS and not post it up..

Comment: If you are expecting answer, you should definetely add your CSS, even better make demo at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Please provide a link to your page, or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo. To be clear: I want a live demo that I can use IE's Developer Tools on.

Comment: ok will add css connected to this tomorrow, didnt think all unrelated css-rules like margin, width etc. was neccessary so I tried to include things that were relevant, but I get the point :)

Answer (score 0):

Without your code its difficult to answer however you need to set the z-index on the parent divs as well, its a common issue I fix in IE6/7 since I have to support them as well.

You might not need to go up as far as the form but without your css and seeing it live it's difficult to say - this or thereabouts will fix it though!

You need position to have a valid z-index, dont worry about other z-index on the page etc..since this is encapsulate within the form; of course change the values to whatever you want, but that is ordering.

```
<form class="current-status" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
    <div class="talk-bubble" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
      <div class="connector" style="position:absolute; z-index:2"> "Absolute positioned with high z-index.." </div>
      <textarea style="position:relative; z-index:1"> "User status goes here" </textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: changed the positioning and indexing according to your suggestion and the textarea still sits on top of the connector in IE7, works everywhere else though(as most solutions). Will have to try to find out a way around it.. thanks for the suggestion anyhow!